# International to international transfer time in LAX

Tags: airport-transfer, lax

I'm flying to LAX by Korean airline and from there to Cancun by interjet. But their schedules allow me only 2 hours for transfer. I wonder if I could make it on time? Cheers.

Comment: What citizenship are you?  Will you be checking bags?  Is the trip on one ticket or two (ie, are you buying the two flights together or separately)

Comment: @Doc I’m Korean and yes there will be bags for check-in and the tickets are separated. (All my answers are making me feel unlucky.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No way.

For international flights, you need to check your luggage two hours before - that's a hard limit.

Even if you'd travel with hand luggage only and in business class, with immigration and customs, you'd have only a small chance to make it.
Note that you lose your second flight, including its return trip, if you miss it - no refunds.

You should also consider potential arrival delays. For separate tickets, book at minimum a six hour difference, better eight hours. Or book it on one ticket, then it is the airlines problem.

Comment: *"that's a hard limit"* -- Any evidence for that?

Comment: https://www.interjet.com/CheckIn.aspx?culture=en-US

Comment: @npl: https://www.interjet.com/CheckIn.aspx?culture=en-US. Most airlines have defined this as the hard cut-off; for domestic flights it is typically 1 hour.